# How do I add my text to the iOS calendar access permission alert?

Tags: ios, calendar, user-permissions

The [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LocationServices.html) state:

> You can provide text that appears in the alert, below a
>   system-provided title such as ““App Name” Would Like to Access Your
>   Contacts”

Where? There's no option for me to add my own message in `EKEventStore`'s `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:` method. I want to add a completely new calendar to the user's calendar store, not modify an existing one, if that matters.

Am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` key to your `info.Plist`  and that should be enough

Source : [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

> NSCalendarsUsageDescription (String - iOS) describes the reason that
> the app accesses the user’s calendars. When the system prompts the
> user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the dialog box.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: So if I want to have translations of this string I have to translate my Info.plist file? Is there any way I can avoid having to do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html . Search for "Localizing Property List Values" . This might help you.